# AttributeError: 'ModuleSpec' object has no attribute 'load_data_wrapper'

Tags: python, linux

This is a bit long so bear with me.

I am trying to learn both Python and Linux and am very new to both. I am currently doing some reading on deep learning from the following:

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

I am attempting to import the `mnist_loader` package to use the associated data for testing the script that was previously written. However, upon typing `import mnist_loader` into the Linux command line, I was given the following:

"the program 'import' can be found in the following packages:"

at which point it listed some packages. Because I'm new to Linux and I don't have admin privileges, I decided to go a route that I understood better; that is to create a new python script and simply use the import command within (which has worked in all previous attempts).

I created a python script and tried `import mnist_loader` and received the following error:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnist_loader'"

I then checked my C drive and found that the file was indeed there. Here is a link to the Git repository where the files may be found:

https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython35

Next I moved on to trying to directly input the path to the file as follows:

```
import importlib.util

mnist_loader = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("mnist_loader",r"C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\src\mnist_loader.py")

training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
```

However, this produced the following error:

> "AttributeError: 'ModuleSpec' object has no attribute 'load_data_wrapper'"

Note: the last line is used to collect the necessary data from the nist files.

I am running out of thoughts at this point and would love some feedback on all my "wrongdoings" up till now.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. It is worth noting that the book uses a package designed for Python 2.X whereas I am using 3.6. The readme provided by the book file location mentioned a different location where a Python 3.6 version could be found which is what I am going with.

Comment: `import` must be run from a python prompt, not the Linux command prompt.  Try opening a Linux terminal command prompt in the folder where you pulled the repo then  `python -c "import mnist_loader;print(len(mnist_loader.load_data()))"`.  Or type `python` to start a python prompt, then try `import mnist_loader`.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I have worked with Python, but I have some ideas as to what would cause the specific errors you are seeing. First I would suggest setting a `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable with the path you have that contains the module you want to import, this does not require administrator privileges fortunately. As for the load_data_wrapper attribute, you might have to do a from `from mnist_loader import *` to import all the functions inside the mnist_loader module.